# import error while import deepface in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, deep-learning

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c84542f3b18d> in <module>
----> 1 from deepface import deepface

ImportError: cannot import name 'deepface' from 'deepface' (C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\deepface\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. It should be `from deepface import DeepFace` per the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/deepface/).